# Is there a way to control the format of the results you get from an emailed HTML form's results?

Tags: javascript, html

I made a form using Javascript and HTML and have a "send" button on it that sends the results of the form to a pre-set email.  In a previous form I made using just HTML, the results I received in the email were neat, each field on it's own line like this:

```
<br>date=
<br>time=
<br>place=
```

But the results from the JavaScript and HTML form run together like this:

date= time= place=

How can I get it to be neat like the pure HTML form?

Comment: You likely have to just format the email using javascript.  An example would help us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sooo sorry about this.  Turns out it wasn't the code, it was a weird thing Outlook was doing to the received email.  Outlook was "removing extra line breaks" from the received email and all I ended up having to do was click the option to "restore line breaks".  Thanks to Corey, Replete, Gerrat, and Ash for taking the time to help me!  Again, soooo sorry to waste all you guys' time! >_<

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `<br/>` at the end of each 'line'.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending a plain text email, try /n after each one to start a newline.  Otherwise you need to set the type of the email to text/html and then put the `<br />` after them.